# How to Obtain Ruby Library for C (MinGW-w64/Windows)

Tags: c, ruby, windows, mingw-w64

Currently, I am trying to run Ruby in a C program. However, I am at a complete loss on where to begin.

What I'm trying to accomplish is outlined in this really helpful guide:
http://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/embed/

However, it starts with using a gcc command that has `-lruby` within it. How may I obtain the Ruby library for compiling? (And specifically have it be for MinGW-w64).

---

I have tried using RubyInstaller (https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2), but still cannot find anyway to obtain a library.

I've also tried compiling the source from the Ruby Github (https://github.com/ruby/ruby), but once again, no luck.

---

Any detailed explanations for an idiot like me would be appreciated. ^^

Comment: `RubyInstaller` should have installed a library and headers. Look under `<RubyInstaller install folder>/RubyX.X.X/include/ruby-X.X.X/ruby` (`X.X.X` being the ruby version) for the headers. Not sure where they squirrel away the lib off-hand...

Comment: @lurker Yeah, I was able to find the header files no problem, it’s just the library that seems to evade me. >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem recently and found 2 ways of obtaining the library:

- When you get Ruby from [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), you can find `ruby.dll.a` file (e.g. `libx64-ucrt-ruby310.dll.a`, depending on the version) in `lib/` folder of your installation directory. You can use it for linking, but you'll need to also include all DLL files from `bin/` (i.e. copy them next to the exe or whatever).
- If you compile Ruby from source, you will get a `.lib` file that you can link (dynamically, or statically using `-static` one). It's probably a better option if you need to use a specific compiler.